# Is there any variable rename plugins for Sublime text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2

I'm using the Jetbrain WebStorm IDE, but I love Sublime Text, so if I got a renaming plugin for Sublime, I will drop my WebStorm, its so heavy for me.

Comment: You mean other than `Find\Replace...`?

Comment: @martel Find\Replace is a not syntax analysis process, it may error like this:


var **a** = 1;
var object = {
  a: 'a'
};

so if i replace "a" to "b", the result may like this:


var b = 1;
var object = {
  b: 'b'
};

[sorry about the text format... ]

Comment: then you need to specify which language you're working with, each language has its way to define a variable and refactoring variable names is therefore language dependant

Comment: oh, i'm writing Javascript, but i didn't found a plugin can do this.

Answer (score 31):

Sublime 2 has built-in functionality.

1. First select the word you need rename (I used word instead of
   variable or function because it is applicable to ANY text file).
2. Click Ctrl+D, multiple times. Each time you click Ctrl+D, it is
   going to select the next Occurence (most people miss the 'multiple'
   click part).
3. Finally you can rename all highlighted occurences at one go.

There might be a better plugin out there, but this works right out of box.

Comment: Not really enough - at the very least it needs to track all relevant files (including unopened) and replace in those as well; and in any case 'variable renaming' explicitly means *syntax-aware* find&replace, that doesn't replace words that just happen to match.

Comment: On a mac you can do Cmd+Ctl+G once to achieve the same effect. (Or in the menu: Find > Quick Find All.)

Answer (score 8):

One of the best place to find plugins in on Will Bond's [Community Sublime Packages](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/community) site.

There is a [plugin for python refactoring](http://sublimerope.readthedocs.org/en/latest/refactoring.html) and one for [javascript](https://github.com/s-a/sublime-text-refactor), but no general-purpose one (yet).

Answer (score 3):

In the same file you can use multi-selection. 
- Quick Add Next (cmd/ctrl + D), which automatically adds the next occurrence of whatever you have selected.
- Quick Skip Next (cmd/ctrl + K) for skip ocurrence.

Answer (score 2):

I took a quick look at: https://github.com/s-a/sublime-text-refactor is this what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Both [emartel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/269211/emartel) and [james](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2014807/james) are right. A full refactor/rename isn't currently possible.

However, if you're code is pretty simple and you just want to rename a variable or a function early on before things get complicated, [emartel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/269211/emartel)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543883/is-there-any-variable-rename-plugins-for-sublime-text-2#comment20286450_14543883) is spot on.

Using `'Find -> Replace'`(or `CTRL-H`) and then `Replace` or `Replace All`can be just what you're looking for sometimes.